Async Python - Bidirectional communication with a child process with named pipes
Got a question about reading and writing data from a child process using named pipes.
I have a pygls language server running as a child process from my main program.
if not os.path.exists(fifo_in_name):
    os.mkfifo(fifo_in_name)
if not os.path.exists(fifo_out_name):
    os.mkfifo(fifo_out_name)
try:
  fifo_in = os.open(fifo_in_name, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
  fifo_out = os.open(fifo_out_name, os.O_WRONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
except OSError as e:
  logger.error(f"Failed to open FIFO: {e}")
  raise e


process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
    sys.executable, 'lsp/lsp_server.py', fifo_in_name, fifo_out_name,
)

In my lsp_server.py, I launch my server like this:
@contextmanager
def open_fifo(name, mode):
    fd = os.open(name, mode | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    try:
        if mode & os.O_RDONLY:
            file_obj = os.fdopen(fd, 'rb', buffering=0)
        elif mode & os.O_WRONLY:
            file_obj = os.fdopen(fd, 'wb', buffering=0)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unsupported mode")
        yield file_obj
    finally:
        file_obj.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fifo_in = sys.argv[1]
    fifo_out = sys.argv[2]
    with open_fifo(fifo_in, os.O_RDONLY) as f, open_fifo(fifo_out, os.O_WRONLY) as r:
        server.start_io(f, r)
        print("Started LSP server")

I'm getting OSError: [Errno 6] Device not configured: '/tmp/fifo_out' when trying to open fifo_out from my main program. I'd be grateful for some guidance on properly using pipes for bidirectional communication.

Why go through the bother of named pipes when the automation will set up anonymous ones for you out-of-the-box?

Mostly out of ignorance- I couldn't figure out how to do non-blocking I/O with my child process from my parent process

Did not run the program, but each pipe should have a writer and a reader. What is "in/out" on one side is "out/in" respectively on the other side. However, it looks like your "in" pipe is open for reading by both sides and "out" for writing on both sides.

@SIGHUP One pipe per stream (1 for stdin, 1 for stdout) is correct, because a pipe is unidirectional. Otherwise a program could read back what was sent by itself.

@SIGHUP Pipes (doesn't matter if anonymous or named) are unidirectional. Please read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)

@ohss117 See the examples in https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#subprocesses using stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE and stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE -- that's what I was referring to re: letting the Python standard library take care of setting up anonymous FIFOs for you.

@SIGHUP Named pipes are not different in this regard. I left a comment below your code and I'm not interested in further communication.

To resolve the issue of “OSError: [Errno 6] Device not configured” when trying to open fifo_out from your main program, consider using anonymous pipes instead of named pipes (FIFOs). Anonymous pipes are automatically set up by the operating system when creating a subprocess. Modify your code to use anonymous pipes, and ensure that your child process (lsp_server.py) correctly reads from and writes to its standard input and output streams. This approach simplifies communication and avoids the need for explicit pipe configuration.
Example  :
import asyncio
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pipe

def child_process(pipe):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe(duplex=True)
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        sys.executable, 'lsp/lsp_server.py', stdin=child_conn, stdout=child_conn
    )

    parent_conn.close()
    child_conn.close()


Not correct to say "automatically set up by the operating system" -- they're set up by Python code explicitly, not the OS. If you let the OS do the thing it does by default, the child process just gets a copy of the parent's descriptors (so writing to the child's stdout goes to the same place as the parent's stdout, writing to the child's stderr goes to the same place as the parent's stderr, etc). stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE tells the standard library to do the necessary work (no need for a separate Pipe explicitly created).
